# Duplicate ID in view with iterations and composite components

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, composite-component, mojarra

I have a strange error that only happens sometimes and I can't figure out what is going wrong.
I get the following error:

> Component ID form_lpm:PODports:PODlocalChargeTable:j_idt1665:j_idt1667:chargeDiv has already been found in the view.

Okay we all know that you can't have duplicate IDs in JSF but that ID above doesn't actually exists!
I have something like this:

```
    <ui:repeat id="PODport">
       <p:dataTable id="PODlocalChargeTable">
            <p:columns>
                <my:compositeComp/>
            </p:columns>
       </p:dataTable>
   </ui:repeat>
```

The composite component (my:compositeComp) has an ID chargeDiv in there.
So in the error message j_idt1665 is the dynamic ID for the p:columns iteration and j_idt1667 the ID for the composite component.

However in the actual generated HTML we get these IDs (as you would expect): The green counter is for the ui:repeat, the blue one for the dataTable and the orange one is for the p:columns.
[image]

At first this page is rendered fine (with the IDs shown above) but when I do an ajax request and update the form I get the error with the duplicate ID. The strange thing is that the counters are removed from that ID. Why is that and what can I do?

I have tried to specify IDs for the p:columns (dynCol) and the composite component (compId) and interestingly I now get pretty much the same error but one of the counters is still in the ID:

```
 <ui:repeat id="PODport">
           <p:dataTable id="PODlocalChargeTable">
                <p:columns id="dynCol">
                    <my:compositeComp id="compId"/>
                </p:columns>
           </p:dataTable>
       </ui:repeat>
```

> Component ID
>   form_lpm:PODports:PODlocalChargeTable:dynCol:2:compId:chargeDiv has
>   already been found in the view

I had the problem with two different composite components. The components were basically just something like this:

```
<p:outputPanel id="chargeDiv">
    content
</p:outputPanel>
<p:tooltip for="chargeDiv">
    tooltip content
</p:tooltip>
```

I am using JSF 2.1 (Mojarra 2.1.29-08) and Primefaces 6.1.18

**Update:**
I have done a bit more testing and it is definitely related to the use of composite components.
If I have a very simple composite component:

```
 <cc:implementation>
        <p:outputPanel id="chargeDiv">

        </p:outputPanel>

    </cc:implementation>
```

and I have dynamic columns like

```
<p:columns var="myvar" value="#{bean.list}" id="dynCol">
   <my:compositeComp/>
</p:columns>
```

I get the error with the duplicate ID.
If I use the content of the composite component directly in the p:columns:

```
<p:columns var="myvar" value="#{bean.list}" id="dynCol">
       <p:outputPanel id="chargeDiv">
           content
       </p:outputPanel>  
    </p:columns>
```

then it works fine.

Comment: Tried a newer jsf version and a newer PrimeFaces version? And if you don't use a composite component it works? If so, then why did you not post its code?

Comment: Unfortunately we are stuck with JSF 2.1 and Primefaces 6.1 for now due to other legacy code. I had the problem with two different composite components. They were basically just a p:outputPanel (with ID) and a p:tooltip for it

Comment: Oh and keep in mind that a composite component always is a namingcontainer. So the 'for' should not point to a sibbling but to an ancenstor. So you should reference it differently

Comment: Believe me, I wish we could upgrade and hopefully one day in the not so distance future we will. But for now it means I have to rewrite the code to not use composite components.

Comment: Thanks for that link. That would be an option to avoid having to specify an ID in the composite component itself